# How do I dismiss the console in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

I accidentally hit the <kbd>`</kbd> today on Don't Starve.  The screen began to display the console information.

How do I make the text go away without quitting the game?  The usual suspects like <kbd>esc</kbd> were not helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wait, I just figured it out.

You hit <kbd>Control-L</kbd> while the input box is not present on screen.

Comment: Nice figuring :)

Comment: I wound up watching a video on how to use the console to made mods in-game, and sure enough, at the end they told me how to do it!  Score one for patience!

Comment: Damn, doesn't work at least in the linux version.

Answer (score 1):

you can also save and quit your game, go to the title screen and join the game again

Comment: Would work, but is complicated.